# how to use target in onclick event

Tags: php, html, css

Hi iam new to php and html ,here i have one resolution,i just upload a picture in database as well as upload folder.and i put download button also.the download button is working to download as same window.but i have to show in new window.please see my code.

```
<input type="submit" onclick='this.form.action="download.php"' 
       name="agreement" id="butt_down" 
       value="<?php echo _l('Dowload'); ?>" class="submit_button">
```

#### download.php

```
foreach($_POST as $name=>$value)
{
    echo karthik;
    if($value=='Dowload')
    {
        if($name=='agreement'){
            $filename=$_POST['filename1'];              
        }
        if($name=='invoice'){
            $filename=$_POST['filename2'];
        }
    }
}
$baseurl='uploads/'.$filename;    
header("Location:$baseurl");
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your input in a form. This way you can remove the javascript completely

```
<form action="download.php" method="post" target="_blank">
<input type="submit" name="agreement" id="butt_down" value="<?php echo _l('Dowload'); ?>" class="submit_button">
</form>
```

Comment: i hope you won't mind, but form `target` attribute is deprecated. http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_form_target.asp

Comment: Indeed. I was just looking at that myself. They don't mention what it has been deprecated in favor of, though.